# Translate 'Mark Step as complete' Button

Tags: community, translation

We are trying to translate our community pages to Japanese.

For the most part, we are using SFDC OOTB translations. For one of the standard buttons ,which is 'Mark Step as Complete', the translation shows up with one word still in English.

We are not able to find the Key ID for that button as well to translate it ourselves (probably because it's a standard button). Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or is making a custom button the only way ahead, which is not worth the effort IMO. Screenshot below:

[image]